# What purpose does the adjective "monotonically" serve in the context of a "monotonically increasing/decreasing function"?

Tags: functions, terminology, monotone-functions

Why employ the adjective "monotonically" when referring to an "increasing" or "decreasing" function? Forsooth, if the function is indeed exhibiting an upward or downward trend, it is inherently "monotonic". Thus, it would seem that the term "monotonically" serves no purpose but to belabor the point, leading one to question its necessity.

Comment: @Randall I thought "monotone" meant possibly not strictly.

Comment: You're right, I'm backwards.  The point is to parse out the possibility of remaining constant on pieces.

Comment: Maybe we can consider a function on a finite interval that goes up and down but whose final value is greater than the initial one: in this case we may say that overall it increase, but not monotonically.

Comment: or a piecewise function that is increasing on each interval of definition but makes jumps downwards. I'd call such a function "increasing" but not "monotone"

Comment: All human languages are to some extent redundant.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC redundancy in language is  used to clarify or emphasize a point, what point is being stresed in this case?

Comment: Some people say $f$ is increasing if $x<y$ implies $f(x) < f(y)$.  This is sometimes called "strictly increasing" to differentiate it from the similar (but different!) concept of "monotone increasing":  $x< y$ implies $f(x) \leq f(y)$.  They are definitely different.

Comment: I don't think there is consensus on this wording. Forsooth, I might be concerned that "monotonically increasing" means the function is increasing and its *rate of increase* is monotonic. Do you have specific examples?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function#In_calculus_and_analysis

Comment: @student91 That seems strange to me.  Texts I've seen define increasing and monotone-increasing to both mean $x \leq y$ implies $f(x) \leq f(y)$ (no downward jumps.)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA you have a good point but we don't use "increasing" in the mentioned sense.

Comment: @student91 such a picewise function would not be considered increasing because, well, the function drops as when we move from left to right.

Comment: @Randall This terminology is confusing because by "montone increasing function" it naturally feels, atleast to me, that the function is "only increasing" (i.e. strictly increasing; not remaining constant or decreasing). It is "increasing function" for which we should have weaker condition.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I suspect that for "strictly increasing", earlier uses were phrases such as "steadily increasing" and "continuously increasing", and perhaps at some point (1930s? 1940s?) authors began using "strict" (or something similar) to avoid possible conflicts that might occur between fuzzy natural language meanings and more precise mathematical meanings, with "monotone" for the non-strict version. For example, "steadily" could convey that the rate of increase is constant, and "continuous" could convey that continuity of functions or a continuous order type is involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use *monotone increasing function* instead of “monotonically increasing function.”

*Monotone* is an adjective, so it modifies the noun *function*. Same for *increasing*. Thus, a *monotone increasing function* is one that is increasing, and also monotone. It's redundant, yes, but unambiguous.

*Monotonically* is an adverb, so it modifies the adjective *increasing*. So a *monotonically increasing function* is one that is increasing in a monotonic fashion. That might be considered ambiguous.

I looked in Courant's calculus text and found the former, and Apostol's calculus text and found the latter. Stewart uses either “increasing,” “decreasing,” or “monotonic” to mean one or the other. Spivak doesn't use “monotonic” at all, just “increasing” or “decreasing.”

If the Wikipedia page bothers you, just edit it. I read the talk history, and it could use some work.

Answer (score 1):

Reasonable question! A **monotonic function**  literally is either an nonincreasing or a nondecreasing function.

If the function has been identified as nondecreasing or strictly increasing or increasing or the like, then the adjective "monotonic" (or the adverb "monotonically") is redundant, perhaps even ambiguous. Is the former suggesting that non-monotonic increasing functions exist? Is the latter (since the dictionary, non-mathematics definition of "monotonic" is "unchanging") suggesting that the second derivative is constant?

Similarly, a **strictly monotonic function** is a function that is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing; here, appending "monotonic" or "monotonically" again doesn't add value.

> @student91: a piecewise function that is increasing on each interval of definition but makes jumps downwards. I'd call such a function "increasing" but not "monotone"

This function is neither monotonic nor increasing, but is possibly injective.

---

**Addendum**

Usage frequency sorted based on Google seach results:

1. "**increasing function**" -monotonically -monotone -monotonic

   1,270,000 results
2. "**monotonically increasing function**" -"monotone increasing function" -"monotonic increasing function"

   277,000 results
3. "**monotone increasing function**" -"monotonically increasing function" -"monotonic increasing function"

   78,000 results
4. "**monotonic increasing function**" -"monotonically increasing function" -"monotone increasing function"

   53,200 results

Answer (score 0):

It might be to avoid ambiguities for people in different disciplines. In order theory one says "order preserving" synonymous to "increasing" in analysis. But an "increasing" map is $f:P\to P$, where $P$ is a poset, such that $x\leqslant f(x)$ for all $x\in P$.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the wording *monotonically increasing* is influenced by a tradition which uses *increasing* in a strict sense, i.e., $x<y$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(x)<f(y)$. Instead of *weakly increasing* (or increaing in the wide sense) many people prefer to say *non-decreasing*. But then functions which are not increasing need not be non-increasing -- and in order to avoid such a confusion, people feel better with *monotonically non-decreasing* (alternatively, one could say *nowhere decreasing* although this does not seem to be common).

It seems to me that such nonsense is a relict from times where all orders were total orders, so that, e.g., *non-negative* as the logical contrary of $x<0$ is indeed equivalent to $x\ge 0$. Nowaday, in many branches of mathematics, partial orders are much more important than total orders.

Answer (score -1):

Monotonic function are function which preserve the ordering relation such that:

$$ x\leq y\Rightarrow f(x)\leq f(y)\text{ for increasing functions}$$

Or reverse the ordering relation:

$$x\leq y\Rightarrow f(x)\geq f(y)\text{ for decreasing functions}$$

For example, the function $\exp(-x) + \cos(x)$ is decreasing but not monotonically. The property of monotonic function it's use to manipulate inequality in all the domain of a given function. If you want to see for the derivative, is monotonic the function if the first derivative is either positive or negative for all the domain, the function $x + \sin(x)$ is positive because it's derivative is always equal or bigger than $0$.

Comment: What is your definition of decreasing so that $\exp(-x) + \cos(x)$ is decreasing?

Comment: @JairTaylor I don't now if it is a good definition but I would say that $\exp(-x)+\cos(x)$ is decreasing because it's bounded by decreasing functions with the same domain, but that definition only would work if the domain is not bounded.